# apt-key adv --keyserver is not working in kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

I am trying to install spotify in kali linux from [here](https://www.spotify.com/int/download/linux/). But when i am trying to add key, it showing "keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
".

```
~# apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.TbRA9iHxcq/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
```

i tried same for other applications,but i am getting same error. Any solution ?